# UITextField to hold upto 10 numbers before decimal place and upto three numbers after decimal

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am looking for a code that allows me to hold upto 10 numbers before decimal place and upto three numbers after decimal.

Valid examples are:
1234567899.123 - maximum 10 numbers before decimal and 3 after decimal position.

123.123 - less than 10 numbers before decimal okay.

123456.1 -  less than 3 numbers after decimal okay.

123 -  Okay

I am using this function below:

```
-(BOOL)textField: (UITextField*)tectField shouldChangeCharactersInRange: (NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString*) string {

    NSString *newStrn = [textField.text stringReplacingCharactersInRange: range withString: string];

    NSArray *arrayofStrn = [newStrn componentsSeparatedByString:@"."]; //to keep only one decimal
    if([arrayofStrn count]> 2) {

        return NO;
    }
    else {

        return YES;
    }
}
```

Do not know how to proceed further to keep max limit of 10 numbers (less than 10 okay) before decimal and maximum limit of 3 numbers after decimal (less than 3 numbers or no numbers after decimal okay).

Thanks very much guys!

Comment: Do you want the numbers to round ? or just not allow entry ?

Comment: Not allowing entry is fine, no need to round it.

Comment: Is the actual code in use?  I ask because the method name is `componentsSeparatedByString`

Comment: @David thats just for future use to check for only one decimal place. in if([arrayofStrn count] > 2)

Comment: My point being that the code you've posted won't compile because of a spelling error.  Your best results from SO are going to be achieved by putting out a best faith effort at solving the problem and then posting a specific question.

Comment: @David : With my full faith: the method name is componentsSeparatedByString. Just edited the post. Thanks for the correction :)

Comment: I posted an answer, i gotta catch a train so i can't perfect it .... Q.Q so you will have to make due with what i have given you ):

Comment: @A'saDickens Thanks very much!! Yes, I will implement your logic and see how it goes and post the new code once it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could achieve this with a simple regex like this

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string;
{
  NSString *editedString = [textField.text stringReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

  NSString    *regex     = @"\\d{0,10}(\\.\\d{0,3})?"
  NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regex];

  return [predicate evaluateWithObject:editedString];
}
```

I've tested the above with the following inputs

```
@"1234567891",      //=> YES
@"12345678912",     //=> NO
@"1234567891.122",  //=> YES
@"1234567891.1234", //=> NO
@".123",            //=> YES
```

Comment: genius man!! Thats the closest logic for my question. This code works perfect, but allows me to put 14 numbers straight if I do not use decimal. I need only 10 numbers in all if I do not use decimal. Cool man, I will learn more about regex.

Comment: Ooops was missing another backslash before the period - updated and should work now

Comment: Nopes! the another backslash does not allow me type anything.

Comment: Sorry I actually tried it this time - my bad. I've made everything from the period and on optional

Comment: very close man!! Now it allows 10 characters before decimal but does not allow me to to type anything after decimal.

Comment: Works perfect now!! Man!! Thank you very much, regex is so good, iOS is so good, this world is so good. Thanks everyone, and thanks SIr Paul.s genius.

Comment: I do not have enough reputation to mark your answer correct :( But that is genius.

Comment: bwahahah i forgot regular expressions exist :3 kudos

Answer (score 0):

Inside your else statement put the following:

```
if([arrayofStrn count] < 2) {
    if ([[arrayofStrn objectAtIndex:0] length] > 10) {
        //Bad
    } else {
        //Good
    }
} else {
    if ([[arrayofStrn objectAtIndex:0] length] > 10 || [[arrayofStrn objectAtIndex:1] length] > 3) {
        //Bad
    } else {
        //Good
    }

}
```

Just as a note, you can retrieve the length of NSString like so:

```
theString.length or [theString length]
```

Comment: I get NSRangeException error when hitting a backspace! :( index 1 beyond bounds [0..0]

Comment: if([arrayofStrn count]> 2) should be good for checking decimal? if this is not true then we perform your code:if ([[arrayofStrn objectAtIndex:0] length] > 10 || [[arrayofStrn objectAtIndex:1] length] > 3) {
    //Bad
} else {
    //Good
}

Comment: Need two checks. First to see if array has more than two objects, then to see if array has just one or two objects. If just one, test against 10. If 2, test against 10 and 3

Answer (score 0):

Here's Xcode 10 and Swift 4.2

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {


    if textField == txt_Amount{
        let amountString: NSString = textField.text! as NSString
        let newString: NSString = amountString.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string) as NSString
        let regex = "\\d{0,6}(\\.\\d{0,2})?"

        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", regex)
        return predicate.evaluate(with:newString)
    }

    return true
}
```